# How do I reliably split a string in Python, when it may not contain the pattern, or all n elements?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

In Perl I can do:

```
my ($x, $y) = split /:/, $str;
```

And it will work whether or not the string contains the pattern.

In Python, however this won't work:

```
a, b = "foo".split(":")  # ValueError: not enough values to unpack
```

What's the canonical way to prevent errors in such cases?

Comment: In Perl, what do `$x` and `$y` get if the string doesn't contain the pattern? Are both of them assigned the entire string, or does `$y` get null or something?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: `$x` gets the whole string, `$y` is `undef` (which is similar to `None`, but subtly different).

Comment: What is the expected behavior when they contain multiple instances of the split pattern? Also, is the pattern argument in Perl's `split` a regex or a regular string?

Comment: @jpmc26: in Perl it would ignore additional values.  But I doubt we really want to write a Perl emulator in python.

Comment: @cdarke Of course we're not writing a Perl emulator, but we can't answer the question without knowing what the desired behavior is. An important aspect of the OP's code that they omit from the question is that the Python version would also fail if the string contained *multiple* colons. Anyway, [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) seems to contradict you. It looks like Perl returns a list, splitting at each occurrence of the pattern, the same as Python's `split` function. It also appears that Perl's `split` is accepting a regex.

Comment: @jpmc26 A Perl list is not the same as a python list, it is closer to a tuple, except you can't have a variable of type list in perl, and you can't have  reference to one either.  A list in Perl is really only a syntactical device.  There is a discussion here:  http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl.  Yes, Perl's `split` is closer to `re.split` except there is extra magic for whitespace.

Comment: @cdarke Your comment only highlights my point: we need clarity on what the OP requires because of the differences between the two languages. It is not enough to say, "I want what this other language does." The "what" needs to be clarified into actual behaviors that are required.

Comment: The "correct" way, in Python idiom, is to try it and catch the exception. Exceptions are very fast in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? What do you want it to do? You have to specify as we are not mind readers.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you're splitting into just two parts (like in your example) you can use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to get a guaranteed argument unpacking size of 3:

```
>>> a, sep, b = 'foo'.partition(':')
>>> a, sep, b
('foo', '', '')
```

`str.partition()` always returns a 3-tuple, whether the separator is found or not.

Another alternative for Python 3.x is to use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> a, *b = 'foo'.split(':')
>>> a, b
('foo', [])
```

This assigns the first split item to `a` and the list of remaining items (if any) to `b`.

Answer (score 60):

Since you are on Python 3, it is easy.  PEP 3132 introduced a welcome simplification of the syntax when assigning to tuples - *Extended iterable unpacking*.  In the past, if assigning to variables in a tuple, the number of items on the left of the assignment must be exactly equal to that on the right.

In Python 3 we can designate any variable on the left as a list by prefixing with an asterisk *.  That will grab as many values as it can, while still populating the variables to its right (so it need not be the rightmost item).  This avoids many nasty slices when we don't know the length of a tuple.

```
a, *b = "foo".split(":")  
print("a:", a, "b:", b)
```

Gives:

```
a: foo b: []
```

EDIT following comments and discussion:

In comparison to the Perl version, this is considerably different, but it is the Python (3) way.  In comparison with the Perl version, `re.split()` would be more similar, however invoking the RE engine for splitting around a single character is an unnecessary overhead.

With multiple elements in Python:

```
s = 'hello:world:sailor'
a, *b = s.split(":")
print("a:", a, "b:", b)
```

gives:

```
a: hello b: ['world', 'sailor']
```

However in Perl:

```
my $s = 'hello:world:sailor';
my ($a, $b) = split /:/, $s;
print "a: $a b: $b\n";
```

gives:

```
a: hello b: world
```

It can be seen that additional elements are ignored, or lost, in Perl.  That is fairly easy to replicate in Python if required:

```
s = 'hello:world:sailor'
a, *b = s.split(":")
b = b[0]
print("a:", a, "b:", b)
```

So, `a, *b = s.split(":")` equivalent in Perl would be

```
my ($a, @b) = split /:/, $s;
```

NB:  we shouldn't use `$a` and `$b` in general Perl since they have a special meaning when used with `sort`.  I have used them here for consistency with the Python example.

Python does have an extra trick up its sleeve, we can unpack to any element in the tuple on the left:

```
s = "one:two:three:four"
a, *b, c = s.split(':')
print("a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c)
```

Gives:

```
a: one b: ['two', 'three'] c: four
```

Whereas in the Perl equivalent, the array (`@b`) is greedy, and the scalar `$c` is `undef`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'one:two:three:four';
my ($a, @b, $c) = split /:/, $s;
print "a: $a b: @b c: $c\n";
```

Gives:

```
Use of uninitialized value $c in concatenation (.) or string at gash.pl line 8.
a: one b: two three four c:
```

Comment: How would it work if you put a variable to the right of `b`?

Comment: @Panzercrisis it's robust - `a,*b,c = "foo:bar:baz:last".split(":")` gives `a="foo"` `b=["bar","baz"]` `c="last"` EDIT: It will die if you don't give it enough values for the definite things, i.e. the same statement with `"foo"` being split will `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)`

Comment: @magu_ It does a different thing. `str.partition` performs only *one* split. So it's like passing `maxsplit=1`.

Comment: @magu_ From what I can glean from the Perl documentation, the behavior here is also closer to the Perl code the OP posted. This will split the string over all elements and stuff everything but the first into a sequence of some kind, which is what Perl's `split` does. The biggest difference between this and the Perl code is that the Perl version's input is a regex.

Comment: @jpmc26: Not exactly. In Perl, if you assign the result of `split()` to two scalars you get either two strings, or a string and an `undef`, but never a string and array reference.

Comment: @jpmc:  because of the behaviour of lists in Perl (not the same as lists in Python), additional elements on the RHS are ignored.  `split` does return all the elements (as the doc says), but if the list on the LHS is too short then additional elements are lost.

Comment: @magu_ that's because Python 3 is more pythonic than Python 2 :)

Answer (score 21):

You are always free to catch the exception.

For example:

```
some_string = "foo"

try:
    a, b = some_string.split(":")
except ValueError:
    a = some_string
    b = ""
```

If assigning the whole original string to `a` and an empty string to `b` is the desired behaviour, I would probably use `str.partition()` as eugene y suggests. However, this solution gives you more control over exactly what happens when there is no separator in the string, which might be useful in some cases.

Comment: This would not work if the string contained *multiple* delimiters, e.g., `'a:b:c:d:e'`

Answer (score 17):

`split` will always return a list. `a, b = ...` will always expect list length to be two. You can use something like `l = string.split(':'); a = l[0]; ...`.

Here is a one liner: `a, b = (string.split(':') + [None]*2)[:2]`

Answer (score 4):

How about using Regular Expressions:

```
import re 
string = 'one:two:three:four'
```

in 3.X:

```
a, *b = re.split(':', string)
```

in 2.X:

```
a, b = re.split(':', string)[0], re.split(':', string)[1:]
```

This way you can also use regular expressions to split(i. e. \d)