# How can seperate the string in python

Tags: python

Here how can i split the string into sub string like follows:

If my string is `'python'` then it need to store like `a1=py, a2=th, a3=on`.

But the input will get by input() function. How can do it?

Comment: Are you trying to split every two characters?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to split each two characters and that need to store in variable. Is it possible in for loop

Comment: Maybe you wanna check out the concept of slicing?

Comment: Yeah, you can use a for loop. You can google the version you commented with :) You can't really google what you originally asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reliably split a string in Python, when it may not contain the pattern, or all n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38149470/608639), [Split string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4998629/608639), [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743806/608639), [Is there a way to substring a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/663171/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
s='python'
a1,a2,a3=[s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),2)]
print(a1,a2,a3)
```

Output

```
py th on
```

If you need to use input and variable split length

```
s=input('Enter String: ')
n=2
a1,a2,a3=[s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),n)]
print(a1,a2,a3)
```

Output

```
Enter String: python
py th on
```

Comment: s=input("enter the string")  the input may different length as per the length, the variable need to increase like a1,a2,a3,a4,a5

Comment: @NaveenS Was already in the process of editing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
If you want to get `2` length substring from given string.

```
In [114]: a
Out[114]: 'python'

In [115]: [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
Out[115]: ['py', 'th', 'on']
```

You can make `2` a variable, depending on which length substring you want.

Comment: good pythonic solution (Y)

Comment: Thanks @Tamim !