# Python3 - How to read words from a list as keys, and then count and store their occurrence as values to the keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am getting information from a file which has content such as the one below:

`1:Record:Place1:Ext12
 2:Record:Place2:Ext2
 3:Record:Place1:Ext19
 4:Record:Place1:Ext12`

I am trying to store words such as Place1 and Place2 in dictionary as keys and then count their occurrences and store the integer `count` as values to those keys respectively.

```
file = open('./Records.txt', mode='r')
d_file = file.read()

location = dict()
count = 0

for item in d_file.splitlines():
    items = item.split(':')
    key = items[2]
    if key == items[2]:
       count += 1
       location[key] = count

print(location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) feature in the collections module. (Click to read official documentation)

It does exactly what you want. It takes an iterable or mapping and returns a dict of keys and number of occurrences as value.

```
from collections import Counter
#open file, etc
keys = [item.split(':')[2] for item in d_file.splitlines()]
print(Counter(keys))
```

In the above snippet, a list of all key occurrence is made according to your format, then a dictionary of number of occurrences is printed.

The file is assumed to have correctly formatted lines, so `item.split(':')[2]` exists. I recommend looking at this answer for safer str partitioning [How do I reliably split a string in Python, when it may not contain the pattern, or all n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149470/how-do-i-reliably-split-a-string-in-python-when-it-may-not-contain-the-pattern)